# wrap post with div in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm using the code below to show the posts, but I need every post to be wrapped with li or div. Currently all is ul. How can I do that?

thx!

```
<?php global $post;
$categories = get_the_category();
foreach ($categories as $category) :
?>
<h3 class="naslovostalih">Ostali članci iz ove kategorije:</h3>
<ul class="clanciostalih">

<?php
$posts = get_posts('numberposts=15&category='. $category->term_id);
foreach($posts as $post) :
$title = get_the_title($ID);
$link = get_permalink();
printf('<a class="linkpost" title="%s" href="%s">%s</a>', $title, $link, $title);
the_post_thumbnail('thumb-232');
the_excerpt();
?>
<p class="more-link-wrapper2"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="read-more     button"><?php _e( 'Opširnije &raquo;', 'fearless' ); ?></a></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>

</ul>
```

I've tried this :
    
    Ostali članci iz ove kategorije:

```
<?php
$posts = get_posts('numberposts=15&category='. $category->term_id);
foreach($posts as $post) :
echo ('<div class="onepost">');
$title = get_the_title($ID);
$link = get_permalink();
printf('<a class="linkpost" title="%s" href="%s">%s</a>', $title, $link, $title);
the_post_thumbnail('thumb-232');
the_excerpt();
?>
<p class="more-link-wrapper2"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="read-more     button"><?php _e( 'Opširnije &raquo;', 'fearless' ); ?></a></p>
echo ('</div>');
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>

</ul>
```

Comment: So make this `<ul class="clanciostalih">` as `<div class="clanciostalih">` ?

Comment: If you want to wrap each post inside the ul as a li, then just echo or print the li tags inside the foreach($post) function.

Comment: I need every post to be wrapped inside of separate div, so I can style them better.

Comment: i tried with printf and echo but I don't get every post wrapped. They are then in just one div.

Comment: @navi show an actual example of the code you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`

```
<?php global $post;
$categories = get_the_category();
foreach ($categories as $category) :
?>
<h3 class="naslovostalih">Ostali clanci iz ove kategorije:</h3>
<ul class="clanciostalih">

<?php
$posts = get_posts('numberposts=15&category='. $category->term_id);
foreach($posts as $post) :
?>
<li>
<?php
$title = get_the_title($ID);
$link = get_permalink();
printf('<a class="linkpost" title="%s" href="%s">%s</a>', $title, $link, $title);
the_post_thumbnail('thumb-232');
the_excerpt();
?>
<p class="more-link-wrapper2"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="read-more     button"><?php _e( 'Opširnije &raquo;', 'fearless' ); ?></a></p>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

`

I think your code had tag opening and closing issues. Try this code. :)